# Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

For my laptop, I got the reserve notice the first of June, and Windows 10 was installed today.  I really like what I have seen. I also have a desktop with:

> Windows edition
>
> - Windows 7 Home Premium
> - Copyright © 2009 Microsoft Corporation
> - Service Pack 1

I haven't noticed the Windows 10 icon on this one. Does this desktop qualify for the Windows 10 update?

Comment: You don't need the icon anymore, just use the [Microsoft Windows 10 tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) that was released.

Answer (score 3):

With the Windows Home Premium it does qualify. The rollout is going in sections so it might take time.

Here is some information on how to get the icon to come up.

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/make-windows-10-upgrade-icon-show-up/

Answer (score 0):

You can manually start the upgrade process by using the media creation tool..

Contrary to what the program is called it can be used to manually start the upgrade rather than waiting for Microsoft to roll the upgrade out to you eventually.

Like any major install/upgrade process, backup any important personal files in the event something goes wrong (shouldn't but never can be too careful)

Download the version that matches the version of Windows you are running (64-bit or 32-bit) at

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

If you don't know if you have 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows do the following to find out:

1. Press **Win+E** (that's the Windows Key)
2. Click **System Properties**
3. Look under **System Type** to see the type of system is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

**Try everything kmg90 suggested.** *If they don't work* and you're sure you have a genuine copy of Windows 7 Home Premium:

- Go to Windows Update
- Make updates and install full automatic
- Check for updates, install any pending update
- If it doesn't work, restore hidden updates, especially the ones for Microsoft products including Office stuff you never use

If it still doesn't work, run a diagnosis on windows update. If there's no apparent fix or fails, your windows update may be messed up beyond repair. My dad's computer has this issue and I'm prepping it for a clean Windows 7 install from DVD.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was modifying the registry this way:

1. Copy the following lines in a file with **reg** extension in your desktop:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade]
   "AllowOSUpgrade"=dword:00000001
   ```
2. Double click the reg file and allow add info in the registry.
3. Check for updates. May take some time.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of initiating the Windows 10 update.  You may want to look at creating media (DVD or USB) and completing an in-place upgrade.  Full details regarding 3 versions of the process can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/08/13/step-by-step-how-to-clean-install-windows-10-without-formatting-the-drive.aspx